# findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStoreIn(Long startTime, Long endTime, List<String> Store) not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to fetch data between given timeStamp and in the given list of stores from `Elastic Index`, but when I'm doing it by looping through the listOfStores it's working fine and I'm getting the data for that particular `store`

```
 listOfStores.forEach( i -> {
            List<InStoreDemographicIndex> inStoreDemographicIndices =
                inStoreSearchRepo.findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStore(startTime, endTime, i)); 
})
```

But at the same time when I'm trying,

```
List<InStoreDemographicIndex> inStoreDemographicIndices = inStoreSearchRepo
.findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStoreIn(startTime, endTime, listOfStores);
```

and passing only one Store at a time, this query is not working and in result I'm getting data for all the stores, even though I'm passing only one Store.

Comment: there is nothing obviously wrong in your code. Have you tried to check what query was generated from your method? Also you could try to write your own query using `@Query` annotation to see what happens.

Comment: Have you checked the log? What query does it actually build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took a long time to get the answer to this problem, but finally got my answer on spring data ElasticSearch under `8.2.2 Query creation`.

[image]

The above query was not working because of the variable `Store` used in the repository method,

`In Service Class:`

List inStoreDemographicIndices = inStoreSearchRepo
.findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStoreIn(startTime, endTime, listOfStores);

`OLD inStoreSearchRepo Repository:`

```
List<InStoreDemographicIndex> findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStoreIn(Long startTime, Long endTime,  List<String> Store);
```

Instead of Store in should be the stores.

`Correct inStoreSearchRepo Repository:`

findAllByTimeStampBetweenAndStoreIn(Long startTime, Long endTime,  List `stores`);

### So in conclusion:

suppose if the field name is `store`,

your repository method should be `List<Object> findAllByStoreIn(List<String> stores);`

Thanks..!!